# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS suspend Screen Issue

Tags: suspend, white-screen

I am using linux ubuntu from last six months. Everything was going good but on 20th January, 2022 I got some updates and after a restart this screen appeared.[White noisy screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcFnb.jpg)
I was shocked that my display or my laptop is damaged. After googling the issue I got to know that its just an software issue, sometimes linux kernel can't make a compatable connection with the hardware specially GPUs so this kind of problems appear.

I went to a linux expert and in BIOS congfiguration he **enabled** **secure boot** option. After that the normal login screen appeared and everything was good.

After few days I realised that the issue is not solved yet.In my settings screen suspension time is 10 min.When I resume from a screen suspention I get the same [White noisy screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcFnb.jpg) and I have to press power button to force poweroff. I think this is not good for hardware also I can loss unsaved files.

I tried many solutions available online but still the problem is not solved.
Then I reinstalled **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** , still not solved.
Changed kernel version to these versions [different kernel versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB4Gr.png) still not solved. Even on changing the kernel display, sound system and networks adaptors don't work properly.

If the issue is not resolved,I have only one option, changing the screen suspension time to **"Never"**, but this will consume more power.
I am totoally fustrated, how to solve this issue ?? Your help will be highly appriciated

My System Info:

Acer nitro 5

AMD Ryzen7 4800h with AMD Renoir graphics

NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1050

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Linux 5.13.0-28-generic

Gnome Version 3.36.8

Comment: What happens if you start memtest at the boot screen?
Does it start or freeze after some seconds?

Comment: Please try this fix I have posted:
[Fix for White screen on AMD APUs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396495/ubuntu-20-04-lts-white-screen)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to swap out the display driver, to "something else" than the one you currently use.

You may well have got an updated display driver, which doesn't work correctly; go back to an earlier version.

How:
Hit the Win-key and type "Driver",
click on "Additional Drivers",
let the list update, when done it will indicate which one you have in use;
then select another one (I suggest "an older one") and let it install;
try a reboot and see if the problem goes away...

NOTE: It might be necessary to go back several steps.

---

No success with the above?

Try checking log files:
Open a terminal, type `dmesg | less` hit ENTER, hit `/` and type e.g. `fail` and ENTER, check any found instances and what they might stand for... repeat for `error` or any other words you might think of...

Report back your findings. (Edit your post above, type `<hr>` and add info below it).

You might also try looking in all files in `/var/log/`  in the same manner... (.gz files: `sudo -i` first then, `cd` and `gunzip -c filename.gz | less` )

Comment: And disable Secure Boot again or sign the newly installed Nvdia drivers.

Comment: I tried by changing 7 different drivers avilable in additional drivers, unforetunately no result.

Comment: I tried your second solution and again no result. Thanks for your response. And finally I changed suspension time setting to 'never' for screen suspension. I wasted almost one week just to solve this issue. Finally  I decided to change the suspension setting and back to my normal works. Hope future official updates will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the fix I have posted on the other thread, Your problem seem to be common with AMD APU users,
[Here white screen problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396495/ubuntu-20-04-lts-white-screen):

> When you turn on the PC, you will be greeted with a white screen now simply close the lid so that your PC goes to 'sleep' mode and now open the lid again to 'wake up' the PC now your display will work properly. I have tried this on My PC: HP-245-G5 with AMD APU A6-7310, R4 graphics 500GB HDD, 4GB RAM.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242526)