# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS White screen

Tags: boot, lts, white-screen

Today, i got a white screen after getting message no irq handler for vector (correct me if im wrong with the message), does anyone know how to solve this?
(specs: AMD A6-7310 APU with Radeon R4 Graphics, 500GB HDD, 4GB RAM)

Comment: There is a dearth of actionable information here, making any accurate answer darn near impossible to provide. Could you [edit] your question to include some hardware specifications (specifically whether you are using a Ryzen CPU) and perhaps what you may have been doing before the error appeared? Is this on a new installation, or has the machine been working fine for a while and this is the first occurrence of the issue? Any logs that you can provide will also make it easier to identify possible causes and solutions 

Answer (score 0):

Hi brother I am currently using the same hardware, I could not locate the cause of the problem but found the fix.
When you turn on the PC, you will be greeted with a white screen now simply close the lid so that your PC goes to 'sleep' mode and now open the lid again to 'wake up' the PC now your display will work properly.
I have tried this on My PC:
HP-245-G5 with AMD APU A6-7310, R4 graphics 500GB HDD, 4GB RAM.

The aforementioned issue of white screen is fixed with the latest update of ubuntu 22.04.1 (12th August 2022), means there is no more white screen on boot for my PC.